# What is "Register a class" in C++

Tags: c++, oop

What does it mean "register a class", if we are talking about C++ and OOP, not about register, COM or some other libraries?

Comment: Don't know, you'll have to tell us what context you heard that term used in.

Comment: Agreed, especially since -- it almost sounds like "class" may not really be what you are registering.

Comment: In c++ and OOP nothing. Maybe on Windows, window classes?

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer because of the lack of context. Just guessing what is meant: Some systems use memory management facilities that take over what `new` and `delete` do, and in some of these one needs to "register a class" with the memory management facility before one can dynamically allocate an instance of that class.

Comment: @Praetorian context was in articles about OOD, and it was said something like it is good practice to   plan your classes in the way that for changing some aspect of program it will be enough to write new class, register it and you get different functionality.

Comment: @DavidHammen I wrote a comment to Praetorian above

Comment: This does not make any sense. Like others said c++ and OOP have no such concept of registering classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"context was in articles about OOD, and it was said something like it is good practice to plan your classes in the way that for changing some aspect of program it will be enough to write new class, register it and you get new staff"

Now it seems to me you are talking about the publisher/subscriber pattern. It allows loose coupling between caller and callee.

You can find a C++ implementation everywhere, in the GoF book, or here:
http://rtmatheson.com/2010/03/working-on-the-subject-observer-pattern/

Comment: The problem is that Register can mean different things in different contexts.  For instance, in a case of declaring register variables, sure.  But what if register denotes that a particular entity is adding itself to a queue for events?

Comment: Pointers point to objects, not classes. We lack context, but I don't think it has anyhing to do with what you say.

Comment: Is there any compiler that doesn't ignore this keyword?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be In fact, `register` is deprecated in the latest standard.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: `g++` with `-Wextra` issues a warning if you take the address of a variable marked `register`. Does that count as "not ignoring it"? ;-) Since taking the address is forbidden in C, a C++ compiler that shares code with a C compiler probably might as well make that warning available in the same way that they often include VLAs as an extension in C++.

Comment: We don't know what compiler is addressed here. True, this question is quite absurd and lacks context. HelloHi should ask whoever told him that, not stackoverflow.

Comment: Re *HelloHi should ask whoever told him that, not stackoverflow* -- Plus one for that.

Answer (score 7):

In the context of pure C++, without respect to any specific platoform or library, "register a class" **has no meaning**.  This is not a language concept, nor is it any design pattern I am aware of.

It does however have at least two meanings the Windows world.  For posterity and future readers:

1. You can [register a Window class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  A Window class contains some basic functionality and other parameters that effect how specific windows behave on-screen.
2. You can register a COM class so that specific instances of that COM class can be instantiated by clients.

Comment: context was in articles about OOD, and it was said something like it is good practice to plan your classes in the way that for changing some aspect of program it will be enough to write new class, register it and you get new staff

Comment: I would ask whoever told you about these concepts since this is not c++ or object oriented programming.

Comment: @drescherjm object-oriented design